# How can I get the number of rows affected after executing an update query?

Tags: php, mysql

The following is the code:

```
$count = 0;
$update = $db->query("UPDATE $table SET price = '$price' WHERE sku = '$sku'");
        if ($update->affected_rows) {
        $count++;
        }   
echo $count;
```

After executing the above code, rows are getting updated in the `db`, but value of `$count` is `0`. As per my assumption, the value of $count should be 122, just because 122 rows are updated. I'm not getting why.

When I use the below code,

```
if (!$update->affected_rows) {
            $count++;
            }
```

the `$count` becomes `212`.

I'm not able to understand the behaviour. I would want someone to explain the above code and how it behaves?

Answer (score 5):

Try below code.

```
$update = $db->query("UPDATE $table SET price = '$price' WHERE sku = '$sku'");
        if ($update) {
       printf("Records Updated: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, it help. Thank you. But still I don't get it why `affected_rows` not working in this case.

Comment: @gandrap If you had same price to update then affected row remain false.

Comment: because what i want is when is not `affected_rows`, then to insert new rows. With `if($update)` i can't do it.

Comment: @gandrap, if you had same value that previously has then affected row always return false, according to your condition, read the return values section: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: @jogesh_pi yes, i know that. problem is that is not same value, but it still returning false. for example previous price value was 100,  after update it is 110.

Comment: my mistake. I should do like this if($db->affected_rows == 1)
Thanks both of you guys

Answer (score 0):

$db->query return the object result
try this :
$affected_rows = $db->exec("UPDATE table SET field='value'");
echo $affected_rows.' were affected'
for more http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php